# Readcsv activity issue in Uipath

Tags: file, uipath

I am able to read the data by using read csv activity but it's not storing the data correctly in datatable. If I am using excel write range and writing  to excel all the data storing in single column along with ; and ". Any help could be appreciated. attached the sample csv.

[image: sample.csv]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you use the correct seperator?

Comment: while reading the csv file, if we are using semicolon as delimiter its failing.. how to get the table format of data into data table by read csv activity. or let us know which activity is useful to read the data and store in data table or excel in table format to use the data to fill the forms.

Comment: I have used that activity very often. It works. I think it's something with your csv file. Please make sure the file is ending with .csv. Also do not open it with Excel. Instead use a text editor and open it. Can you show your process? And the parameter you use?

Comment: yes file is ending with .csv, I am not opening with excel. I need to download the file then read that file. after downloading the file directly using in the read csv activity. I am able to read with delimiter comma, if we are using semicolon its throwing an error like csv format is invalid. tried with ignore quotes  and different ways but no luck. here is the screenshot.

Comment: Please export the CSV as "comma seperated" file as the extention says. And then use the activity again. And now show us the datatable.

Comment: Kindly change the semicolon in Read CSV Activity property Options Delimiter value .

Comment: First create csv file data using notepad  and go to save as and use double quote like this "sample.csv". Kindly change the semicolon in Read CSV Activity property Options Delimiter value .

Comment: semicolon delimiter is not working its giving as error like csv file format is invalid.

Comment: I have tried to simulate the issue but can't reproduce any error. Please, paste your input `CSV` as text (not as a picture). Btw., note that you have a semi-column too much at the end of the header row which will create an extra (empty) forth column named `Column 1`.